# Set SelectedValue on ListBox again after changing the ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a `ListBox` whose `ItemsSource` is a `CollectionViewSource` (`ICollectionView`). I use this collection to filter the source/original collection. Now the problem is, in case the filtered collection removes the value which is bound to `SelectedValue`, the `SelectedValue` and the binding property for `SelectedValue` in the view model is set to `null`. Moreover, when the filter changes are undone and the selected value is back in the collection, how do I automatically set the `SelectedValue` again in the `ListBox` which was previously set before applying filter. The collection contains strings.

Related to: [SelectedValue explicit binding updates when ItemsSource change..why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116728/selectedvalue-explicit-binding-updates-when-itemssource-change-why)

Comment: use the `SelectedValueChanged` or `SelectedIndexChanged`event and set Selected value there if it is not set.

Comment: That is possible but I am looking for a more MVVM approach...

Comment: In MVVM you'll have a public property which binds to `SelcetedValue`. You'll have a setter or on this property. Here you can add some logic.

Comment: Yeah you are right! Firing the propChanged at some point does the trick :P